# Read input until a certain number is typed

Tags: java, sum

I need to stop asking for integer inputs when zero is typed as an input and start summation immediately. My program doesn't stop when I type zero. I need it to stop and start summing up all the inputs it has gathered.

Here is what I have:

```
public class Inttosum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer");
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int askool = kb.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;
        int score = 0;


        while(askool != 0){
          score = kb.nextInt();
          sum += score;
        }
    }
}
```

/////////////////The final code which worked..Thank you!
    public class Inttosum {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer");

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum = 0;
    int score = 0;
    do {
        score = kb.nextInt();
        sum += score;

    }while(score != 0);
    System.out.print(sum); 
 }
}
```

Comment: Try comparing value from user... (askool doesn't change in your loop so maybe you should update it, or use other variable which actually stores user input).

Comment: "my program doesn't stop when typing zero. I need it to stop and start summing up all the inputs" => CTRL-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `do-while`

You are using something called `askool` as a loop condition, but updating the variable `score` in your loop. You could use a `do-while` loop. Change

```
while(askool != 0){
    score = kb.nextInt();
    sum += score;
}
```

to something like

```
do {
    score = kb.nextInt();
    sum += score;
}while(score != 0);
```

#### Using `break`

I also suggest calling [`Scanner.hasNextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt--) before calling `nextInt`. And, since you don't use the `score` (just the `sum`) you could write it like,

```
int sum = 0;
while (kb.hasNextInt()) {
    int score = kb.nextInt();
    if (score == 0) {
        break;
    }
    sum += score;
}
System.out.print(sum);
```

Which will also stop (and still `sum` all `int`s) if the user enters text.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help !

Comment: here is the final code that worked:    public class Inttosum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println("Enter an integer");
    
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum = 0;
    int score = 0;
    do {
        score = kb.nextInt();
        sum += score;
        
    }while(score != 0);
    System.out.print(sum); 
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

You are checking `askool !=0` whereas in the while loop values are being referenced by `score`. Change it to `while(score != 0 && askool != 0)`

Comment: aha..Got ya..Thanks !

Comment: Can you select this as an answer then :)

Comment: My dear i wish I could select more than one answer but the other answer is more complete