# How to keep the program running if the user entered Y?

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        {
            System.out.println("What is the answer to the following problem?");

            Generator randomNum = new Generator();
            int first = randomNum.num1();
            int second = randomNum.num2();
            int result = first + second;
            System.out.println(first + " + " + second + " =");

            int total = Keyboard.nextInt();

            if (result != total) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, wrong answer. The correct answer is " + result);
                System.out.print("DO you to continue y/n: ");
            } else {
                System.out.println("That is correct!");

                System.out.print("DO you to continue y/n: ");

            }

        }
    }

}
```

I'm trying to keep the program to continue but if the user enters y and closes if he enters n.

I know that I should use a while loop but don't know where should I start the loop.

Comment: with a loop. If you search the site you will find some examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474882/read-input-until-a-certain-number-is-typed for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a loop for example :

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String condition;
do {
    //...Your code
    condition = scan.nextLine();

} while (condition.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a good attempt. Just add a simple while loop and facilitate user input after you ask if they want to continue or not:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        //The boolean variable will store if program needs to continue.
        boolean cont = true;

        Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // The while loop will keep the program running unless the boolean
        // variable is changed to false.
        while (cont) {

            //Code

            if (result != total) {

                System.out.println("Sorry, wrong answer. The correct answer is " + result);

                System.out.print("DO you to continue y/n: ");

                // This gets the user input after the question posed above.
                String choice = Keyboard.next();

                // This sets the boolean variable to false so that program
                // ends
                if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
                    cont = false;
                }

            } else {

                System.out.println("That is correct!");

                System.out.print("DO you to continue y/n: ");

                // This gets the user input after the question posed above.
                String choice = Keyboard.next();

                // This sets the boolean variable to false so that program
                // ends
                if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
                    cont = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You may also read up on other kinds to loop and try implementing this code in other ways: [Control Flow Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html).